# how to make little arrowbutton on a <hr> (for slideUp/slideDown with JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

quick question,

I have a `<hr>` and this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  $(function () {
         $("#hideClass").click(function () {
             if ($("div#bodyFake").is(":hidden")) {
                 $("div#bodyFake").slideDown();
             } else {
                 $("div#bodyFake").slideUp();
             }
         });
     });
 </script>
```

atm the script is meant to hide the entire body (this was just to test if it worked because I had some JQuery problems)

however, I would now like to have a little arrow/button on the right side of `<hr>` so I can hide the div (the 1 table) underneath it.
[image: screenshot]
Does anybody know how I can get the little arrowbutton on there? (don't know what it's called..)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it a height and a background image.

```
hr {
 background-image:url(....);
 background-position:right top;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;  
 height:20px;   
}
```

Comment: should work but didn't for me (I guess I have the wrong relative url? I have a content map, and in that map is my css + a map Images + my image.
so url should be:  url('../../Content/Images/slideDownArrow.png');   no?

Comment: Use Firefox + Firebug, open up the NET tab and see if you have a 404 error listed for that image filename.

Comment: I can see the image in firefox, but not in chrome :s however, I solved it without an image and just made a div with text underneath (title of the table) underneath the line.

Thanks for the answer though I will most probably be able to use this later on!

Answer (score 0):

I now realize I could also have just used the ASCII-arrow alt+31 ▼ and alt+30 ▲